# React - Pseudo element on Input not rendered at all

Tags: css, reactjs, pseudo-element

I am beating my head here over why an `::after` element is not rendered at all when being on input element, but on some div it renders just fine.

I am trying to make a performance friendly focus effect on an input element, so when it's in focus, it gets a nice glow from the after element.

Here's what I have

```
return (
  <div className="App">
    <input placeholder="Username"></input>
    <div className="divider"></div>
  </div>
)
```

and the css

```
input,
.divider {
  width: 300px;
  height: 40px;
  position: relative;
}

input::after,
.divider::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 16px 3px #61DAFB;
}
```

and here's the final product

[image]

When inspecting the ::after element for the div, it is right there in the screen, event if I remove its dimensions, but for the input element, it's in the DOM, but when you select it it's nowhere in sight.

Why is that?

Comment: @pwolaq I was only searching for React related stuff, because I thought the problem was specific for react.

Comment: Also it's kind of confusing what is a container and what isnt considering how React forces you to write every html element with a closing tag

Comment: this is not 100% right, you can use the short syntax. Like XHTML does. You don't need closing tag, but you need to close it, like XHTML does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`:before` and `:after` render inside a container and  can not contain other elements.

Please view specs: https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/generate.html#before-after-content